# SSRS SWITCH showing error rather than answer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to do a simple calculation for my data. When the Order value = 6, then subtract the values of order = 1 - 2 -3. It returns #error instead of the the answer. How can i make it work correctly?

```
=       SWITCH(
        Fields!Order.Value = 6,
       Sum(IIF( Fields!Order.Value = 1 ,CDBL(Fields!Totals.Value),CDBL(0)))
                - Sum(IIF( Fields!Ordering.Value = 2 ,CDBL(Fields!Totals.Value),CDBL(0)))
                - Sum(IIF( Fields!Ordering.Value = 3 ,CDBL(Fields!Totals.Value),CDBL(0)))
                ,
        1 = 1,Sum(Fields!Totals.Value)
        )
```

Comment: Could you give us some sample data and a sample output of what you expect? Also what error are you getting.

Comment: Order Name Total
1 Apple 24
2 Orange 7
3 Mango 9
4 Grape 4
5 Watermelon 3
6 Banana

Comment: In your provided code you reference 3 fields, "Order", "Totals", and "Ordering", while in your comment you seem to have "Order", "Name", and "Total". is the field you call "Name" in the comment the same as the field you call "Ordering" in your code? if not, what is "Ordering"? Also, what error message is SSRS giving you?

Comment: CDBL your 1 = 1 value. It's trying to mix CDBL and integers, apparently. 
`1 = 1, CDBL(Sum(Fields!Totals.Value))`

Comment: Also, should this be Ordering? `Fields!Order.Value = 1` Order can;t be 6 and also 1. And I think you actually need a single sum outside the switch.